# JAVA - Why getting ElementNSImpl from SOAP UI

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, axis

I am trying to retrieve the values from SOAP UI. I am able to get all element values except one element and getting as "`[prim:Usercount: null]`" instead of Usercount value.

and while seeing in debugging mode, the value for Usercount showing is ElementNSImpl.

Please find the code as below:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "UserListRequest", propOrder = {
    "reference",
    "number",
    "usercount"
})
public class UserListRequest extends Arguments  implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(name = "Reference", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "string")
    protected UserListReferenceTypes reference;
    @XmlElement(name = "Number")
    protected String number;
    @XmlElement(name = "Usercount")
    protected Object usercount;

  //Seeters & getters

    // Type metadata
    private static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc typeDesc =
        new org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc(UserListRequest.class, true);

    static {
        typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://*.*./*.Services", "UserListRequest"));
        org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
        elemField.setFieldName("reference");
        elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://*.*./*.Services", "Reference"));
        elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://*.*./*.Services", "UserListReferenceTypes"));
        elemField.setNillable(false);
        typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
        elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
        elemField.setFieldName("number");
        elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://*.*./*.Services", "Number"));
        elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"));
        elemField.setMinOccurs(0);
        elemField.setNillable(false);
        typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
        elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
        elemField.setFieldName("usercount");
        elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://*.*./*.Services", "usercount"));
        elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "anyType"));
        elemField.setMinOccurs(0);
        elemField.setNillable(false);
        typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
    }

    /**
     * Return type metadata object
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc getTypeDesc() {
        return typeDesc;
    }

    /**
     * Get Custom Serializer
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Serializer getSerializer(
           java.lang.String mechType, 
           java.lang.Class _javaType,  
           javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
        return 
          new  org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializer(
            _javaType, _xmlType, typeDesc);
    }

    /**
     * Get Custom Deserializer
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Deserializer getDeserializer(
           java.lang.String mechType, 
           java.lang.Class _javaType,  
           javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
        return 
          new  org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer(
            _javaType, _xmlType, typeDesc);
    }
}
```

SOAP UI:

```
<prim:XMLRequest>
        <prim:Reference>aa</prim:Reference>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <prim:Number>1</prim:Number>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <prim:Usercount>150</prim:Usercount>
     </prim:XMLRequest>
```

Can anyone please suggest on this.

Answer (score 1):

Your class members aren't consistent. You have

```java
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@XmlElement(name = "Reference", required = true)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "string")
protected UserListReferenceTypes reference;

@XmlElement(name = "Number")
protected String number;

@XmlElement(name = "Usercount")
protected Object usercount;
```

instead of

```java
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@XmlElement(name = "Reference", required = true)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "string")
protected UserListReferenceTypes reference;

@XmlElement(name = "Number")
@XmlSchemaType(name = "int")
protected int number;

@XmlElement(name = "Usercount")
@XmlSchemaType(name = "int")
protected int usercount;
```

Comment: but in wsdl usercount mentioned as anytype so we used as Object. Please help on this.Thanks @William Burnham